# Morris Chart Multi Colours

Tags: javascript, morris.js

Hi Im using the following code for my Morris chart and it is working fine. But I need to make the lines different colours so 1-3 are green, 4-6 are orange and 7-10 are red.

```
    function init_morris_charts() {

        if( typeof (Morris) === 'undefined'){ return; }
        console.log('init_morris_charts');

        if ($('#graph_bar').length){

            Morris.Bar({
              element: 'graph_bar',
              data: [
                {device: '1', geekbench: <?php echo $grade1Value; ?>},
                {device: '2', geekbench: <?php echo $grade2Value; ?>},
                {device: '3', geekbench: <?php echo $grade3Value; ?>},
                {device: '4', geekbench: <?php echo $grade4Value; ?>},
                {device: '5', geekbench: <?php echo $grade5Value; ?>},
                {device: '6', geekbench: <?php echo $grade6Value; ?>},
                {device: '7', geekbench: <?php echo $grade7Value; ?>},
                {device: '8', geekbench: <?php echo $grade8Value; ?>},
                {device: '9', geekbench: <?php echo $grade9Value; ?>},
                {device: '10', geekbench: <?php echo $grade10Value; ?>},
                {device: 'NA', geekbench: <?php echo $gradeNAValue; ?>}
              ],
              xkey: 'device',
              ykeys: ['geekbench'],
              labels: ['No Of Buyers'],
              barRatio: 0.4,
              barColors: ['#26B99A', '#34495E', '#ACADAC', '#3498DB'],
              xLabelAngle: 45,
              hideHover: 'auto',
              resize: true
            });

        }
```

Any ideas how I can do this? I can see that #26B99A is the bar colour but that is the colour for every line.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function in **barColors** that will return a color according to your needs, as follow:

```
    barColors: function(a) {
        if (0 <= a.x && a.x < 3) { return 'green'; }
        else if (3 <= a.x && a.x < 6) { return 'orange'; }
        else { return 'red'; }
    },
```